# LROAuth2Client integration

Tags: oauth-2.0

I'm trying to integrate OAuth2 into my iPhone app.

I want to use LROAuth2Client (https://github.com/lukeredpath/LROAuth2Client).

Although there is a demo (https://github.com/lukeredpath/LROAuth2Demo), I don't know how to recreate this example from scratch (basically struggling with integration).

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: I'm seeing some of the same problems as you with integration. I can get a user to login to foursquare but foursqaure redirects the user to their website. When that happens I make the webview reload the same authenticate url in hopes to get the correct authenticate page. When I arrive at this authenticate page it shows "OAuth Access Request" but doesn't have the allow button I'd need to get the oauth access code.

Comment: check out drewvergara-Foursquare-OAuth-iPhone on github. Looks like a simpler solution. Although I would still like an answer to this one. Cheers.

Comment: I just found that you need to add a parameter to the userAuthorizationRequestWithParameters function: 

[params setValue:@"code" forKey:@"response_type"];